# Generate a report using pentaho java api for hdfs file passing hdfs file path programatically

Tags: java, hadoop, pentaho, kettle

I am new to Pentaho.I have installed Pentaho Enterprise Edition and have set the required configurations for BigData.I was able to run PDI transformation and generate reports using that tool.In my java web application I have downloaded pentaho-kettle jars using maven that are required for generating reports.Is it possible to generate a report for hdfs file by passing hdfs file path dynamically or programatically using report api?If yes what steps  are required to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a pentaho report on a server side. To be able to query hdfs - this report should query PDI transformation/job. When it make attempt to query it - it starts the transformation. So you have to have a full PDI infrastructure to be able to execute this job/transformation.
Separate jars will not help since PDI (also known as pentaho-kettle of spoon) is 'an installation' rather than a library. It is interacts with hdfs using 'shims' as a plugins. This shims has to have a correct structure of folders and config files etc. In Enterprise Edition typically all this is hidden under the hood of enterprise server.

In case you want to use 'my own java web application' - the simplest way to have all working (from my point of view) is to create a kettle transformation, install Carte server (in a neighborhood with your web server or another machine), configure hdfs steps to run on this Carte server.

Technically when launch such report in context of your web application this will trigger kettle transformation execution. This also will call to carte server for hdfs steps. Since Carte server has a correct PDI installation to be able to interact with HDFS - it will fetch HDFS data and send it back to your application. This data will travel through a network since your web application run report: report run transformation, transformation fetch data from carte server, carte server fetch data from hdfs.

You may consider to have a carte server as a localhost only accessible, while expose you web app to external requests. Hope it will help.

Hope it will help.